# Prevent deselection of previous Windows file explorer items when they are modified

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I'm frequently in the position where I've selected a file to copy somewhere, I make a change to the file in an editor, but when I switch back to the directory view my item has been deselected. It is the same file, but it seems that Windows 'resets' it when the file is modified. This is especially irritating when I've selected multiple files from various places in the folder.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: It isn't "the same file" strictly speaking. Any app that overwrote an existing file without a safety-net in case of write-failure, power loss etc, would not be very good in this day & age. It will write a new file first, then delete/hide/archive the old one, depending on the particular app.

Comment: Point taken, however the purpose of the file explorer is to protect the standard user from intricacies such as that. In this situation my application is Visual Studio 2015 and it's only text-based files I'm concerned with. I totally get that DLLs will be deleted and re-created, so they're not even slightly "the same" files, but ASCX files and the like should be trackable by Windows as "pretty much the same as the one you had selected before". I don't think that's unreasonable?

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a way to prevent Explorer deselecting changed files?

As far as I know this is not possible with Explorer.

You could try an alternative file manager.

[xyplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/index.php) does **not** deselect modified files. I've been using it as a replacement for Explorer for some years.

> XYplorer is a tabbed file manager for Windows. It features a powerful file search, a versatile preview, a highly customizable interface, optional dual pane, and a large array of unique ways to efficiently automate frequently recurring tasks. It's fast and light, it's innovative, and it's portable.
>
> - Supported Operating Systems: Windows 10, Server 2014, 8.1, 8, Server 2012, 7, Server 2008, Vista, XP, Server 2003, 2000, NT, Me, 98;
>   32-bit and 64-bit versions.
> - XYplorer is a Portable File Manager. It doesn't require any installation or changes to your system or registry. Take it with you
>   and start it from a USB stick, along with your personal configuration.
>   File management to go.

Source [xyplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/index.php)

There is a freeware version.

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [xyplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/index.php) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.